# Inline Declaration Of Dictionary<> in C# with FOREACH()

Tags: c#, syntax

Can anybody help out with the syntax of something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
         foreach(var i in collection<Items>)
-----add i to dictionary
}
```

Comment: What is `collection<Items>`? Is `Items` some kind of user-defined type? How exactly does it map to a `string` key and a `string` value?

Comment: i just put that in there for example purposes im dealing with all user defined types.  im just looking for an example of how to use the foreach loop in side the declaration body of the Dictionary<> object

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you mean, but the [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298836.aspx) LINQ extension method may help you. For example:

```
var dictionary = collection.ToDictionary(item => item.Key,
                                         item => item.Value);
```

(Obviously you can vary how the key and value are obtained from the item.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = collection.ToDictionary(i => i.MyKey, i => i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like UserCollection.ForEach(d => ...add each d.key and d.value to the dictionay and any other logic associated with selecting the key and value), assuming the collection of User types is in a List format or if it's an IEnumerable you can just do .ToList().ForEach(...